# Targeting an element with specific data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the code below. How can I add `.click()` to the `a` link with specific data attribute of `HD`?

```js
if ($(a).data("quality") == "HD") {
  $(this).click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="stream">
  <li><a data-quality="L">Low</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="M">Med</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="HD">HD</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a click on the element, or add a click event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$("a[data-quality=HD]").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="stream">
  <li><a data-quality="L">Low</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="M">Med</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="HD">HD</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of [Attribute Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector):

```
$('a[data-quality="HD"]').click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly bind the click to the *anchor* with *data-quality attribute*

**Demo**

```js
$("a[data-quality='HD']").click( function(){
  console.log($(this).text()) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="stream">
  <li><a data-quality="L">Low</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="M">Med</a></li>
  <li><a data-quality="HD">HD</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

pure js approach

```js
window.onload = clickAnchor();

function clickAnchor() {
let anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<anchorTags.length;i++) {
if(anchorTags[i].getAttribute('data-quality') == 'HD') {
     anchorTags[i].click();;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="stream">
  <li><a onclick = "alert('low clicked')" data-quality="L">Low</a></li>
  <li><a onclick = "alert('med clicked')" data-quality="M">Med</a></li>
  <li><a onclick = "alert('HD clicked')" data-quality="HD">HD</a></li>
</ul>
```